# Node JS: my SQL callback function return data to server or broadcast to room id

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Node JS : my SQL callback function return data to server or broadcast to room id

1]  Server.js

```
var express     = require('express');
var app     = express();
var http    = require('http');
var server  = http.createServer(app);
var io      = require('socket.io').listen(server, {log:false });
var dbAction    = require('./dbAction');
var yql     = require('yql');

server.listen(config.port);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket)
{
   socket.on('userAuthentication', function(loginDetails){
    var test = dbAction.userAuthentication(loginDetails);
    console.log(test);
    console.log("---------------");
   });
});
```

---

2] dbAction.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var userInfo = {};
var connection = "";

exports.userAuthentication = function(info)
{ 
    userInfo.unm = (info.unm).trim();
    userInfo.pwd = (info.pwd).trim();

    connection = mysql.createConnection({host: "localhost", user: "root", password: ""});
    connection.query('USE user');
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='"+ userInfo.unm +"'", function(err, results)
    {
        if (err) { console.log(err); }
        else if(results.length > 0)
        {
            var key = (results[0]['key']).trim();
            if(key != ""){

                var select_sql = "another query";
                connection.query(select_sql, function(err, results_1)
                {
                    if (err) { console.log(err); }
                    else if(results_1.length > 0)
                    {
                        console.log( results_1);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

**Queries:**

1] I want "result_1" return to server.js "userAuthentication" in test variable.

2] Otherwise "result_1" broadcast to specific room.

Answer (score 0):

Add the socket as a parameter, then you can use the socket object to emit in a room.
You could also add the io object but i think it's better to give only the socket, if you want to broadcast for example.

server.js

```
var test = dbAction.userAuthentication(loginDetails,socket);//NEW
```

dbAction.js

```
exports.userAuthentication = function(info,socket)//NEW
{ 
userInfo.unm = (info.unm).trim();
userInfo.pwd = (info.pwd).trim();

connection = mysql.createConnection({host: "localhost", user: "root", password: ""});
connection.query('USE user');
connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='"+ userInfo.unm +"'", function(err, results)
{
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
    else if(results.length > 0)
    {
        var key = (results[0]['key']).trim();
        if(key != ""){

            var select_sql = "another query";
            connection.query(select_sql, function(err, results_1)
            {
                if (err) { console.log(err); }
                else if(results_1.length > 0)
                {
                    console.log( results_1);
                    socket.to(ROOM_ID).emit('result', results_1);//NEW
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Thanks for comment,
but I already try this "pass socket as a parameter".

using this parameter 
"socket.to(ROOM_ID).emit('result', results_1);" 
this not worked.